# sending values from servlet in link to jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, url-parameters

I need to send a reset password link from my servlet to my jsp page.

I am generating html message and send it as a email to user that requested password-change.

Once he clicks on that link, it will take parameters that are in the link and will open  Reset-Password-Page.jsp

So, here is what I have...

SendEmail.java

```
...
String server = "localhost";
int randNum = 25364;
String practiceName = "blueCross";
msg.setContent("<p>Hi there,</p><br /><a>We received a request to reset your password. <br />To reset your password and access your account, click the link below.</a><br />"
                        +"<a href=\"<%= server%>:8080/RSIwork/ConfirmedResetPasswordPage.jsp?randNum=<%= randNum%>&practiceName=<%= practiceName%>\" Click Here </a>",
                        "text/html" );
        Transport.send(msg);
...
```

This generates url:

```
http://localhost:8080/RSIwork/ConfirmedResetPasswordPage.jsp?randNum=257&&practiceName=usr
```

This is good, but I am not getting these parameters in my servlet...

ConfirmedResetPasswordPage.jsp

```
<form id="frmLogon" action="changePasswordLDAP" method="post">
    <table> 
        <tr>
            <td class="style2">Username:</td>
            <td><input id="username" type="text" name="userName"  autocomplete="off" required/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style2" >New Password:</td>
            <td><input id="rdNewPassword" type="password" name="newPassword"required/>             </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>                                                   
            <td><input id="practiceName" type="hidden" name="practiceName" value="<%request.getParameter("practiceName");%>"/></td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
            <td><input id="randNum" type="hidden" name="randNum" value="<%request.getParameter("randNum");%>"/></td>
        </tr>
```

changePasswordLDAP.java

```
String practiceName = request.getParameter("practiceName");
String userName     = request.getParameter("userName");
String newPassword  = request.getParameter("newPassword");
String randNum      = request.getParameter("randNum");
System.out.println(practiceName  + userName + newPassword + randNum);
```

But this doesn't print randNum and practicename

CAn someone tell me if I am doing anything worng. I must be...

Comment: If I understand correctly, you expect the string send by SendEmail.java to have `<%= server %>` replaced by the value of the local variable `server` defined before. Why would that happen? Also, forget about scriptlets. Learn the JSTL and the JSP EL. And HTML-escape your variables.

Comment: If you're in java you shouldn't write jsp commands. You can change this: `msg.setContent("...")` to 
`msg.setContent("<p>Hi there,</p><br /><a>We received a request to reset your password. <br />To reset your password and access your account, click the link below.</a><br />"
                        +"<a href=\""+server+":8080/RSIwork/ConfirmedResetPasswordPage.jsp?randNum="+randNum+"&practiceName="+practiceName+"\" Click Here </a>" + "text/html" );`

Comment: @JBNizet I need to send these parameters somehow through this link, so when the user clicks on the link I will know what practice he belongs to.

Comment: @t.pimentel yea... I had it originally that way, but it would still loose values when I submit the ConfirmedResetPasswordPage.jsp and I don't know why??? :(

Comment: `<%request.getParameter("practiceName");%>` should be `<%= request.getParameter("practiceName") %>`, or better, with the EL: `${param.practiceName}`. Learn the EL. scriptlets should not be used for 12 years.

Comment: Do the values get to the ConfirmedResetPasswordPage.jsp page? (You can check with inspect element on chrome or firefox) Ps: you also didn't close the `<a href...>` tag with ">"

Comment: @t.pimentel yes. it generates folowing url: http://localhost:8080/RSIwork/ConfirmedResetPasswordPage.jsp?randNum=257&&practiceName=usr

Comment: Use firebug (Firefox) or inspect element (Chrome) to monitor the network requests and see if the parameters are being sent through the POST request. Also check if the values of the hidden items are filled correctly in the html with this tools.

Comment: @t.pimentel but my servlet is not getting those values, even thought they are passed in url :(

Comment: What I'm saying is to check still when the ConfirmedResetPasswordPage.jsp page is opened in the browser, if the `<input id="practiceName" type="hidden" name="practiceName" value="<%request.getParameter("practiceName");%>"/>` is having its value filled.
And then, in the network tab of inspect element in chrome, see if the post to changePasswordLDAP.java had which parameters in it.

Comment: @t.pimentel I can see the output in Tomcat window. It is nto printing these 2 values. I am still reading on how to get them from url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59432/discussion-between-t-pimentel-and-angelina).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @JB Nizet in the comments this:

```
<%request.getParameter("practiceName");%>
```

Should actually be:

```
<%= request.getParameter("practiceName") %>
```

Notice both the added "=" and removed ";".

Besides that, to check for this type of error, click with the second button in the web browser and select inspect element. Then search for the part of the code you want to debug in the html and see if it's showing correctly.

In this case it would look like this:

```
<input id="practiceName" type="hidden" name="practiceName" value/>
```

Instead of:

```
<input id="practiceName" type="hidden" name="practiceName" value="practiceNameValue"/>
```